# Will clEnqueueMapBuffer always return the same address for the same CL buffer?

Tags: opencl

If I use clEnqueueMapBuffer to map the same CL buffer several times, can it guarantee to return the same address? For example, if I have:

```
ptr1 = (float *) clEnqueueMapBuffer(commandQueue, buffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, bufferSize, 0, NULL, NULL, &errorNumber);
// do something here
ptr2 = (float *) clEnqueueMapBuffer(commandQueue, buffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, bufferSize, 0, NULL, NULL, &errorNumber);
```

Will ptr1 and ptr2 always be the same?

If not, is there any way to test if two pointers (i.e. ptr1 and ptr2) are mapped from the same CL buffer?

Answer (score 1):

No, they won't necessarily be the same, although depending on the implementation, and you're repeatedly mapping the same region, there's probably a good chance they will be if you haven't mapped any other buffers in the interim. Note that [you can have multiple simultaneous overlapping mappings *for reading*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html#notes), which already implies that they can't have the same address:

> Multiple command-queues can map a region or overlapping regions of a memory object for reading (i.e. `map_flags = CL_MAP_READ`).

To compare pointers, simply test them for equality, **but note that you can only have multiple simultaneous buffer mappings *for reading*** - host-mapping for writing, or write access from a kernel are exclusive operations, and any concurrent read or write access from the host or another kernel is undefined. So the "do something here" in your code **must** include an `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject` call for ptr1, as you're using `CL_MAP_WRITE`.